# Compute the data lost between original data set and transformed one using PCA

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

I am using sklearn in Python to do Principal component analysis.

One of my intentions is to generate a 4 components model, another with 8 and compare both with original data using inverse_transform.

The code is something like this:

```
pca4 = PCA(n_components=4)
pca4.fit(parkinsonData)
scores4=pca.transform(parkinsonData)
reconstruct4=pca.inverse_transform(scores4)
```

To compute the difference between original data and the reconstruction I did:

```
differenceMatrix=parkinsonData-reconstruct4
```

Now I have the differences, but I would like to compute the data lost respect original data set. To do this I want to compute the mean of the differences powered by 2 between each element of original data set and the reconstructed one.

In the last statement I compute the differences between each element of original data set and the reconstructed one, but now I have to compute the power. I do not know how to do this, because when I use:

```
power=differenceMatrix**
```

I get an error: This matrix is not square.

To solve this I use

```
np.power(differenceMatrix,differenceMatrix)
```

It works but some elements are NAN. I understant that it is due of the lack of the square shape.

Anyone knows how to solve this, and compute the data lost between original data set and transformed one using PCA?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To square (I guess that's what you mean with "powered by 2") each element of the matrix, use:

```
np.square(differenceMatrix)
```

This works element-wise and does not restrict you to matrices of square shape. NaNs in the matrix are returned as NaN in the output.

Comment: That was the solution.

Thanks @acidtobi